# Android build error after adding google map activity

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an android project that was running perfectly untill I added Google maps activity using the built-in activity in android studio,
The error is 
[image]

The error occuring in this file:
[image]

I searched for this error, and the solutions were that I need the sdk tool build to be equal to the app compat, but I already have this:
[image]

Comment: the problem is two different versions of Google Play Services. Either use 11.0.2 or 8.1.0, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this on your Gradle module file

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
```

Have you made sure that you added your Google API key to the application?